# Rails not playing HTML5 video

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, video

The video works fine on my pc, but for some reason, I can't play it on my site. It shows the control buttons, and even the time starts running, but there's no video:

[image]

The code on my page:

```
<video width="100%" height="auto" controls>
  <source src="/videos/aquaflow__video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The video is located at: `app/public/videos/aquaflow__video.mp4`

Is there something I'm forgetting?

Comment: You can't add question changes in answer. please modify your question and add extra lines

Comment: Have you tried to upload into `assets/images` folder?

Comment: Sometimes video is badly encoded/corrupted, so it can be played by your media software, but not by your browser. Try opening .mp4 directly (localhost:3000/videos/aquaflow__video.mp4) or via static html page. If it doesn't work you should reencode it (avidemux etc..)